# use angular 2.0 in aspnet application

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have asp.net application and we are building new project which is in Angular 4.0 and i just want to know how to redirect from already existing .aspx/ascx file to the new angular 4.0 index.html. I tried respose.redirect but it just laods the index.html content. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some code for proving how far did you try and helping others members to understand better your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my idea on your issue.

Do you have a seperate controller to access the new Angular app?
Does it work?

In that case, the bulletproof solution should be
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Angular") to get the index method of the AngularController.

or please share some details on your code

Comment: Its not a asp.net MVC application. Its a simple asp.net website application and we are adding a new feature and thats done in Angular 4.0. I have a new menu for this new Angular4.0 and new angular page should open inside the already existing asp.net master page like other pages.

Comment: Ifi understand you correctly, why don't you use a partial view?

Comment: do you have any example link for that?. As i said my application is not MVC application.